# Toggling stylesheets in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ternary-operator

What we wish to to do is to toggle themes using the functions
when the page loads initially its is in the moon_theme 
both the themes as located in localpath css
what is not working is the comparison in the ternary operator
it always returns false, so is the boolean expression wrong ? 
for comparing the style sheetname how should we use it 
we tried give the whole path also dosent help

functions are working as we also have separate calls to them and they are working fine

```
function toggle_theme() {
var a = document.getElementById("pagestyle");
a.x == 'sun_theme' ? theme1() : theme2();
}

function theme1(){
var a = document.getElementById("pagestyle");
a.href = 'css/sun_theme.css';
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Atlas";
}

function theme2(){
var a = document.getElementById("pagestyle");
a.href = 'css/moon_theme.css';
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Europa";
}
```

and Sorry about the ill formatted question

Comment: What's your problem and what is your question? Your "question" was also pretty hard to read, can you add some punctuation to make it easier to parse through?

Comment: as @TheFluffyProphet wrote, one can only guess what your problem is. What doesn't work here?

Comment: what's the problem? where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Guys Sorry about that,  I am new to stack overflow

Answer (score -1):

found the solution

if (a.href.match("sun_theme.css"))

```
theme1();
```

else

```
theme2();
```